# What is the best way to clear controls on an ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net

After data is entered on a web form and then comitted to a database or whatever, what is the best way to clear the contents of the various text box controls and return combo boxes to a non-selected state?  I know this can be done from the code behind but is not the best way since it requires a round trip to the server.  I know javascript is also an option but I am not very familiar with it at all so is there another option or is Javascript the best way?

Thanks

Comment: See http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml

Comment: Looping through all of the controls on a form: http://www.krissteele.net/blogdetails.aspx?id=104

Comment: Aren't you already making a round trip to the server anyways to post the data?  Javascript or Code-behind logic would suffice equally here.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm making an assumption that you are doing a post back to the server in your form to save the data to begin with.

After you've processed the form (i.e. saved the data to the DB) why don't you clear the controls from the page and call "[CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx)".  This would be the quickest way to clear your input controls before rendering the page back to the user.

YMMV, this isn't necessarily the best or safest way to do this but it can/could work; however I've only used this in custom controls that did not have a corresponding ascx file.